# How to determine whether block is orphaned?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, blocks, confirmations

I've been working on a high stakes contract, which is deployed using the web3 v1.0 library. An important condition for robustness is ensuring the contract has been confirmed 12 blocks prior (at the very least).

This is easily done with the new confirmation 'PromiEvent' convenience feature, but a lingering question remains. What happens if the chain my contract is on gets abandoned? How does one check that (with web3 v1)? I doubt the confirmation event itself changes any data in the receipt. Does it stop firing perhaps? Here's some sample code:

```
        newContract = await BigContractParent
              .deploy({ data: BigContractCompiled, arguments: [100, accounts[0], accounts[1]] })
              .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '2000000', value: web3.utils.toWei(JSON.stringify(req.body.val), "ether") })
              .on('transactionHash', function (transactionHash) { console.log("Txn hash is: " + transactionHash) })
              .on('receipt', function (receipt) {
                console.log(receipt);
                console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + receipt.contractAddress + "  Contract blocknumber: " + receipt.blockNumber) 
              })
              .on('confirmation', function (confirmationNumber, receipt) { 
              if (confirmationNumber > 12) 
                 console.log("Congratulations! You are safe! ", confirmationNumber, receipt) });

        //send response with newContract, wait for 12th confirmation...
```

Comment: Interesting question: I would expect that ``on('confirmation')``automatically handles chain reorgs, and continues counting the confirmations on the new longest chain. Anyway, you'll need to handle the timeout somehow.

Comment: @ivicaa - the arbitrary time for contract confirmation causes headaches with Express setups, but a timeout shouldn't interrupt event callbacks in the queue, unless I'm mistaken. CRUD functions should run fine.